# How to set PHPStorm get existed word to autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

In `Sublime Text`, when I have `helloWorldTesteStringLong` written in an open file, it will show in auto complete list, independence if I in their file or not

How to can I set this configuration in PHPStorm? For show written word in autocomplete list

Comment: *Random* word from another file -- not possible AFAIK. The only close functionality is `Code | Completion | Cyclic Expand Word`

Comment: Great!! This is useful for me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Hippie Completion (Alt+Slash) - https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/hippie-completion-expanding-words.html